# Trigger a focus and then mousedown event

Tags: javascript

So I'm using Froala for my rails application and it has a bug to where it doesn't auto resize the iframe upon load to accommodate all of the text that's in it.

However, if you click inside of the iframe where the body is and you press an arrow key (like moving the cursor), then it auto expands.

How could I go about auto simulating this event so that I can temporarily fix the problem that I have? Here's what the froala editor looks like:

```
<iframe src="about:blank" frameborder="0" class="fr-iframe" style="height: 265px;">
   <html>
      <head>
         <style data-fr-style="true">html{margin:0px;height:auto;}body{height:auto;padding:10px;background:transparent;color:#000000;position:relative;z-index: 2;-webkit-user-select:auto;margin:0px;overflow:hidden;min-height:70px;}body:after{content:"";display:block;clear:both;}body::-moz-selection{background:#b5d6fd;color:#000;}body::selection{background:#b5d6fd;color:#000;}body{font-family: Verdana, Georgia, serif; font-size: 13px; color: rgb(68, 68, 68);}</style>
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
      </head>
      <body class="fr-view" dir="auto" contenteditable="true" aria-disabled="false" spellcheck="true">
         <p>HELLO WORLD</p>
         <p>HELLO WORLD</p>
         <p>HELLO WORLD</p>
         <p>HELLO WORLD</p>
         <p>HELLO WORLD</p>
         <p>HELLO WORLD</p>
         <p>HELLO WORLD</p>
         <p>HELLO WORLD</p>
      </body>
   </html>
</iframe>
```

In the above example, the iframe height was defaulted to 20px, until I clicked in the iframe itself, moved the cursor left, and then it auto expanded to 265px.

Some of the things I've tried to do trigger this are:

```
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('textarea').froalaEditor('events.keydown', true);
  }, 2000)
```

after initializing the Froala Editor.

I've also tried to trigger a key press event on the `p` and 'body' element, but I'm pretty sure I'm not doing this right.

```
var e = $.Event('keypress');
e.which = 65; // Character 'A'
$('body').trigger(e);
$('p').trigger(e);
```

Comment: What have you tried to achieve the desired effect?

Comment: Updated to reflect answer.

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick:

```
var iframe = document.getElementsByClassName("fr-iframe")[0]
var innerDoc = (iframe.contentDocument) ? iframe.contentDocument : iframe.contentWindow.document;

// get the element in question
const input = innerDoc.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

// dispatch keyboard events
input.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keyup', {'key':'y'}));
```